# Toggle submenu on specific menu(link) click. Jquery

Tags: jquery, submenu

When i click on the name of the photographer, the first  menu pops-up (this works)
When i then click on the first link of the menu (work) a sub-menu should pop-up.
The other links should just have text.
But some how i can't get it to work that the sub-menu shows when clicking on work.
Any suggestions?

Jquery code: (verbergdivs = hide divs)

```
function verbergdivs() {
    $("#content").children().hide();
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    verbergdivs();
    $("#menu").hide();
        $("h3").click(function(){
            $("#menu").toggle("slow");
        });
    $("nav a").click(function(event){
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        verbergdivs();
        $(url).show();              
        $(url).children().hide();   
        $(url).find("h1, p").slideDown(500)
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>
</head>
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
<h3> Marsel van Oosten Photography</h3>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li> <a href=".work">Work</a></li>
            <li> <a href=".about">About</a></li>
            <li> <a href=".news">News</a></li>
            <li> <a href=".contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section id="content">
        <div class="work">
    <nav>
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li> <a href=".people">People</a></li>
            <li> <a href=".objects">Objects</a></li>
            <li> <a href=".series">Series</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="about">
            <h1>About</h1>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="news">
            <h1>News</h1>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.s</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hgF8K/1/

```
<h3> Marsel van Oosten Photography</h3>
<div id="wrapper">
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li> <a href=".work">Work</a></li>
        <li> <a href=".about">About</a></li>
        <li> <a href=".news">News</a></li>
        <li> <a href=".contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="submenu"  class="work">
        <li> <a href=".people">People</a></li>
        <li> <a href=".objects">Objects</a></li>
        <li> <a href=".series">Series</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section id="content">

    <div class="about">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
        <h1>News</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.s</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
</section>

</div>

function verbergdivs() {
    $("#content,#submenu").children().hide();
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    verbergdivs();
    $("#menu,#submenu").hide();
        $("h3").click(function(){
            $("#menu").toggle("slow");
        });
    $("nav a").click(function(event){
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        verbergdivs();
        $(url).show();              
        $(url).children().hide();   
        $(url).find("h1, p, li").slideDown(500)
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: Genius =D this seems to work, gonna try and apply it to my code, thanks!
Edit:
I seem to have one issue, Because i (need to) make the list horizontal.
I get Work, underneath it the sub-menu pops up and then underneath that about, contact shows. Hopefully i can fix this with some CSS

Comment: @Xereoth: I used your original code as a base. You should be able to copy and paste from the jsfiddle. Glad I could help. Accept that answer if this is what you needed.

Comment: I seem to have one issue, Because i (need to) make the list horizontal. I get Work, underneath it the sub-menu pops up and then underneath that about, contact shows. Hopefully i can fix this with some CSS or you got any suggestions for that?

Comment: @Xereoth: which list needs to be horizontal? menu or submenu?

Comment: They Both need to be, You have the name
Underneath the menu
Underneath that the sub menu

Comment: Thanks so much!! :) May the odds be ever in your favor ^_^

Answer (score 0):

That is because you do

```
$(url).children().hide();   
$(url).find("h1, p").slideDown(500);
```

So you only show the `h1` and the `p` elements, but your `.work` div does not contain any such elements..

Comment: At first i tried things like:

$(".work").click(function(){
$("#submenu").toggle();
});

But that didn't seem to work